# java - detect and change encoding

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding

i have a small java app. i develop it in eclipse. it takes text from xml file and uploads it to a website. in eclipse everithing works fine. but when i compile my app to executable jar and start it from cmd a big trouble appears - all non latin characters transform into unreadable symbols.

i've tryed to put `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" ?>` or `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>` however it doesn't help.

how can i fix this problem?

any help appriciated!

Comment: If I remember correctly, try `"Cp850"` (MS-DOS western). If I am right, I would like to cry. BTW not in the XML, but where you write.

Answer (score 0):

You could try specifying the UTF-8 `Charset` (or any other [supported charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html), for that matter) explicitly in your output writer's constructor.

For example, when using the `PrintWriter` class for outputting data:

```
Writer writer = new PrintWriter("myfile.txt", "UTF-8");
writer.write("Hällo Wörld!");
writer.close();
```

An equivalent example when using the `OutputStreamWriter` class:

```
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "UTF-8");
writer.write("Hällo Wörld!");
writer.close();
```

(Note that in both cases the `Charset` has to be specified via its textual name (i.e. "UTF-8"), not by direct instantiation of the respective class.)

Thus, a likely explanation for your problem is that as the charset is not given explicitly, the system tries to fallback to the default encoding of your OS (which is probably not UTF-8).